# Defragmenting SQL indexes

Tags: sql-server-2005, defragmentation

I have been trying to defrag indexes in SQL Server 2005 and nothing seems to work.  I have created multiple Maintenance Plans using the wizard but the job always fails.  I have run the script from this site, which is originally from Microsoft:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/03/04/sql-server-2005-a-simple-way-to-defragment-all-indexes-in-a-database-that-is-fragmented-above-a-declared-threshold/

Even if I go to the specific table in Object Explorer and select the Indexes folder and select Rebuild All the fragmentation % never changes, even though it reports as completing as successful.

Shouldn't a rebuilt index have 0% fragmentation?  If so why would this sql not work:

```
ALTER INDEX [IndexName] ON [dbo].[TableName] 
REBUILD WITH ( PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = Off,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, ONLINE = OFF )
```

This is the sql generated by selected Rebuild Index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are not a lot of rows in the table, or the data does not consume a page of data (8k), you will notice fragmentation of indexes even after rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Although possibly related with a very small database as suggested in other response, the problem is more **likely tied to the FILLFACTOR**.

The ALTER INDEX statement shown does not *explicitly* mention the FILLFACTOR, and hence the rebuilt is done on the basis of the current fillfactor value, leaving a fragmentation that should approximate this factor.  (It is rarely an exact match because a given index entry cannot be split between two nodes, hence making each node possibly leave more or less room than the fillfactor would require; indeed in some cases, this would require an fractional number of bytes... but let's not stray from the real issue...)

You can inquire the current fillfactor value for a given index by looking in the sys.indexes table, with a query similar to 
SELECT * FROM sys.indexes
WHERE object_id IN
  ( SELECT object_id FROM sys.objects
    WHERE name = 'myTableName')

Alternatively if you run a modified version of the ALTER INDEX snipped shown, where
... FILLFACTOR = 100 ...
is added in the "WITH" option, I suspect the fragmentation reported will match your expectation.

For sake of clarity, the PAD_INDEX option only instructs SQL to leave some space in the intermediate nodes of the index, these therefore will not incur any "fragmentation", but the leaf nodes will.

This said...  **It *may* be a good idea to leave a certain amount of fillfactor**, in order to delay in onset of fragmentation as new data is inserted into the table.